# UnicodeDecodeError Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been taking a YouTube course on how to build live-updating graphs in python. Initially, my program wouldn't run because I was missing important modules such as six or dateutil (I even installed pyparsing and pitz to avoid any further setbacks). But now, every time I run it I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jó\Desktop\Live-updating Graphs (YTBCourse).py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1048, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 897, in rc_params
    fname = matplotlib_fname()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 748, in matplotlib_fname
    fname = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'matplotlibrc')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 108, in join
    path += "\\" + b
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You might see/mark this question as a duplicate but I haven't found an answer to this problem in the "Similar Questions" section. I really don't know how to go on from here. Can you help me sort this out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: it looks a bug in `matplotlib`. It mixes Unicode and bytestrings. It should use Unicode filenames on Windows i.e., `os.getcwdu()`. Try Python 3 which is more strict about mixing Unicode and bytes (and therefore the error will reveal itself even on pure ascii filenames).

Comment: I think this is fixed 1.4.x and master.

Comment: see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3487

Answer (score 0):

I see that the directory you use contains special character `ó`

The easiest way is to rename your directory. Something to `C:\Users\Jo\Desktop` instead of `C:\Users\Jó\Desktop`. Or store the Python files somewhere else.

As you can see from the error, `os.getcwd()` gets the current directory and add to the path. Now here in the directory path you have special characters which are not understood by the interpreter's default ASCII source code encoding.

Comment: Is it possible to rename the directory of a user without affecting all the other softwares of the computer?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is your Username, it contains a non-ascii character.

A friend of mine had the same problem, because his user name was "römer".

Thank Microsoft for the nearly non-existing unicode support.